# The Model Derivative API - Zip to Svf translation remain progress 0%

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I have uploaded a zip file to OSS. Then, call API job to translate zip to svf. The result is:

> remaning progress 0%

Why? Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is missing. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If the design file inside the ZIP is too complex, or if our translation workers are unusually busy, the translation may take a while.

If even after several hours the Model Derivative job still reports progress 0%, please contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and share the URN of your model so that we can take a look on our end.